# Translating matlab into python

Tags: python, matlab, code-translation

I'm trying to translate a matlab code, and I'm strugeling to translate this part of the code:

```
[data;SS(ind-1:-1:ind-9)']
```

In the following context:

```
SS = 1:288
year = 1:288
data = [];
for ind = 10:length(year)
    data = [data;SS(ind-1:-1:ind-9)'];
end
```

What I've done at the moment is:

```
SS = range(1,288);
year = range(1,288);

data = [];

for ind in range(10,length(year)):
    data.append(######)   # code to translate
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT: (Output Correction, wrong parameters)

`1:288` is in python `list(range(1,289))` or if you use numpy `numpy.arange(1,289)`.

For index access you have to know, that matlab starts with 1, python with 0, so `SS(ind-1:-1:ind-9)` becomes `SS[ind-2:ind-11:-1]`

```
SS = list(range(1,289))
data = []
for ind in range(9,len(SS)):
    data.append(SS[ind-9:ind][::-1])
```

or using numpy:

```
data = numpy.arange(9,0,-1)[None,:] + numpy.arange(279)[:, None]
```

Comment: thx but the result is not the same, the dimension in matlab is 2511 on the contrary in python youre creating a 271 len of 7 items (1953).